# Where are the logs of php-LDAP interaction on Active Directory

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I can create AD users with php, but when I try to set passwords to enable the accounts, I can an internal server error, I wonder if AD itself store more descriptive log messages? Where can I find those messages and filet by source IP address.

Comment: `internal server error` happened probably on web server side where php-ldap installed. Check web server log

Comment: http://superuser.com/users/164837/alex this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/users/164837/alex was right, for some reason I thought that this comes from AD, but somehow he knows that this is web server error.
The actual error is too specific, so it does not make sense to show that to you.